# How to declare an array with a variable number of elements [C++]?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

How do I [dynamically?] declare an array with an 'i' number of elements?

Comment: You definitely *wouldn't* use malloc.

Comment: You don't "declare" anything dynamically. A declaration is part of the program source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a container of the standard-library instead, most commonly `std::vector<>`.

Other solutions contain manual allocation and deallocation of memory and are probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::vector<T>`. It works like

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.push_back(2);    // add 2 to the array
a.push_back(4);
```

You could go on and on, and you won't need to worry about memory allocation issues.

Comment: `//add 2 to the array` is misleading. `std::array<T>` and `std::vector<T>` are different.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use pointers.
Example:

```
float *ptrarray = new float [10];
```

Basically, type * pointername = new type [i];

And don't forget to clean your memory:

```
delete [] ptrarray;
```

Or it will be reserved until the program ends.

Comment: You don't *have* to use pointers, at least nor explicitly. And use of raw `new` makes for fragile code. Better to use a standard library container, or at the very least some kind of smart pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza you're right. It's just my little English problems. Thank you for useful advises!

Answer (score 2):

**Create a Dynamically Sized Array**

```
std::size_t N = 10;
SomeType *a = new SomeType[N];
for (auto i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}
delete [] a;
```

A C++ array is a pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory containing a specific type.  This snippet allocates space for an array of 10 `SomeType` instances, constructs the array which initializes each object using the default constructor, iterates over the array, prints out each element, and then deallocates the memory by calling `delete []`.

Key Points:

- you are required to call `delete []` to deallocate the array.  The array form is required to ensure that the destructor is called on each object.
- after allocation, there is no way to recover the size of the array.
- you can iterate over the array by index (or pointer)

This is **not the way to do what you want**, keep reading.

**Using a vector**

```
std::size_t N = 10;
std::vector<SomeType> v(10);
for (auto iter=v.begin(); iter!=v.end(); ++iter) {
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

This snippet uses `std::vector` which manages a contiguous block of memory for you.  Note the usage of an iterator to walk over the vector instead of using indexing.  Vectors do support direct indexing so the `for` loop used in the previous example would work here as well.

```
for (auto i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Using an iterator is the *best practice* and idiomatic though using a `for` loop may not be but I digress.

Key Points:

- memory management is automatic in the case of a vector
- you can append using `push_back`
- a vector knows how many elements are in it -- call `v.size()` to get the number of elements
- iteration is performed using the `iterator`s returned from `v.begin()` and `v.end()`

---

Just use `std::vector`.  If you need raw access to the underlying pointer, then use `&v[0]` or `v.data()` but don't do that unless you need to.  Also, don't use `std::auto_ptr` for arrays.  You will be tempted to but don't do it.